# how to reuse tcp session in java for client in javax.ws.rs.client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tcp

i am trying to make 10 requests repeatedly on https service, i am able to do it but i am using 10 tcp connections for this.
I want to reuse the same tcp connection created at start for the 10 requests, how to do it for below code

here client is javax.ws.rs.client

java code:

```
static SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator
  .newInstance()
  .securityProtocol("TLS")
  .keyStoreFile("/path")
  .keyStorePassword("password")
  .keyStoreType("JKS")
  .trustStoreFile("/path");

static SSLContext sslCtx = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
static Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslCtx).build();            

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Response response = client.target(target).path(path)
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.entity(jsonRequest.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is good article about it: [Setting up jersey client 2.0 to use httpclient, timeouts, and max connections](http://www.theotherian.com/2013/08/jersey-client-2.0-httpclient-timeouts-max-connections.html) But actually it is outdated now. Sample for current Jersey client:

```
static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
static Client client;
static{
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
    //you can provide per route settings
    //connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("localhost")), 40);

    SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
            .securityProtocol("TLS")
            .keyStoreFile("/path")
            .keyStorePassword("password")
            .keyStoreType("JKS")
            .trustStoreFile("/path");

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);
    clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
    client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(clientConfig).sslContext(sslConfig.createSSLContext()).build();
}
```

Also you should call `response.close();` to mark connection as free.

By default you use `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager`. It has following notice: *This connection manager will make an effort to reuse the connection for subsequent requests with the same HttpRoute route. It will, however, close the existing connection and open it for the given route, if the route of the persistent connection does not match that of the connection request*

So in simple situation connection is reused by default.

Comment: i am getting unable to find valid certification path

Comment: How to open a connection using a client above

Comment: Your code sample should work without any changes. My sample: 
`Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("/")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`

Comment: yeah i am not changing it, is it because of adding pooling configurartion to client?

Comment: Connection pool is transparent for your code (except initial configuration)

Comment: i have used for client config org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig and for
connection pooling manager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager  is it right

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheClientProperties for apache client properties

Comment: if i make  clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);   to   clientConfig.property("", connectionManager);

then there is no error it is working, but still in wire shark i am getting 10 connections made when i filter with tcp.flags.ack==0 && tcp.flags.syn==1

Comment: how is clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager); having ApacheClientProperties of org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheClientProperties and connectionManager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager   they both are different i think because of that there is a conflict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90335/discussion-between-sibnick-and-labeo).

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but you could try this:

```
Request req =  (Request) client.target(target).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
  Response response = req.post(
    Entity.entity(jsonRequest.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

Comment: getting  org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Request

Comment: You have to cast it to Request. I updated the code above.

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Request   for  Request req =  (Request) client.target(target).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Comment: which request import are you referring to

Comment: i have used Invocation.Builder req =   client.target(target).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

response = req.post(
       Entity.entity(jsonRequest.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


then i got  no errors but in wireshark capture it is showing making of 10 connections